# apache throws 500 when header is large

Tags: apache, header

I use PHP to output custom a custom header:

```php
//build a long header string
$arr = [];
for($x = 0; $x < 1167; $x++) {
    $arr[] = 'cool';
}
header('x-http-myheader: ' . json_encode($arr));
```

I have apache configured with:

```
LimitRequestBody 0
LimitRequestFields 0
LimitRequestFieldSize 999999
LimitRequestLine 999999
```

Running the PHP script works fine, unless you increment `1167` to `1168`. Doing so causes apache to throw 500 Internal Server Error with message: `Premature end of script headers: php-cgi.exe`

Clearly this is a header size or file size limitation, but no matter what I set the LimitRequestX settings to, Apache still throws the error once the header reaches a certain size.

How can I get Apache to allow the larger header?

Comment: It's a perfectly valid header and successfully 'prints' (outputs) until I make the header just a few characters longer by increasing the loop count. The `Limit` settings affect this. For example, if I reduce `LimitRequestLine` to 10, then Apache throws header too large error.

Answer (score 2):

If this appears in your Apache logs:

```
Premature end of script headers: index.php
AH01070: Error parsing script headers
AH01075: Error dispatching request to:
```

you may have a problem with mod_proxy_fcgi: it doesn't accept headers with
a size greater than 8192 bytes.

Here you can see the bug reported in ASF Bugzilla:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64919